# How to highlight specific days in a date picker using Ext js Date picker?

Tags: extjs, datepicker

I am new to EXt js.
Can anyone tell me how to highlight specific days in a date picker using Ext js Date picker?
Without overriding Ext.picker.Date can we achieve the same?

Comment: Any particular reason for not overriding?  You might be able to hack around it with the `tpl` config option, best to check the sencha docs.  But I would have thought it easier to override it and implment the custom function how you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting of dates is not configurable/supported in Ext. You can override the picker - it is not very difficult, I've done it to highlight holidays.